# Using Devbridge Autocomplete, is there a way to detect no results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, autocomplete

I'm using Devbridge Autocomplete (https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete) on an input field type text and reading results from an array.

Is there a way to:

1) Only allow to select from the list of results and not type anything else in the field

2) If no results are found, trigger a function

Code:

```
var people = ['Ross Chapman', 'Curtis Gomez', 'Dolores Gonzales'];

$('.people').autocomplete({
    lookup: people
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use onSearchComplete method as [mentioned in the docs here](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete#configuration-settings).

> onSearchComplete: function (query, suggestions) {}

second parameter suggestions is an array of suggestions as letters are being typed in the input. So by checking `suggestions.length` we can catch the condition when the suggestions array is empty, meaning no results found.

```
var people = ['Ross Chapman', 'Curtis Gomez', 'Dolores Gonzales'];

$('.people').autocomplete({
    lookup: people,
    onSearchComplete: function (query, suggestions) {
        if(!suggestions.length){
            console.log('no suggestion');
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/PSJTQ/21/**

Comment: How do I trigger the function only after a suggestion has been picked and not before that? In this example I want to make the background white again only after something is picked from the list on not while I'm still searching: http://jsfiddle.net/murid/PSJTQ/24/